# start contentview from appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appdelegate

Pls, would you advise?
I am testing some old pod and I am getting "UIAlertView is deprecated and unavailable for UIScene based applications, please use UIAlertController"
I googled somewhere to remove scene delegate, comment out UISceneSession, etc..
I did all the steps and when I start the app the contentview is always black :(

Pls, how to instantiate the Content view from appdelegate?
[image]

Comment: Window will be nil; you need to create an instance

Comment: @Paulw11 exactly :D sorry I just missed to create instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SceneDelegate.swift` doesn't have to be commented, there are some steps you have to be aware of.

- Set a window instance to your AppDelegate `window` property, as @pkc456 recommended.

```swift
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

- Remove the Scene configuration from the AppDelegate (You have already done it by commenting it as showed on your screenshot).
- Delete the Scene configuration key from `Info.plist` file.

`Info.plist` > `Application Scene Manifest` > `Scene Configuration`

Remember to use the `View Hierarchy` debugger, sometimes you are seeing the correct view controller but it doesn't have a backgroundColor.

Hope I Helped!

Comment: thanks guys creating instance of UIWindow works :) I feel stupid

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{   
    let timeline = YourViewController()
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: timeline)

    let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

    window!.rootViewController = navigation
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```